# Solve for $\Sigma$ in $B\Sigma+\Sigma B^{T}=-S$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

Given that $\Sigma_{n\times n}$ and $S_{n\times n}$ are symmetric matrices while $B$ is a non-symmetric square matrix, solve for $\Sigma$ in the equation $$B\Sigma+\Sigma B^{T}=-S$$

This looks so simple but I can't seem to figure out how to solve it. I was imagining using the skew matrices property $\Sigma B^{T}=(B\Sigma)^{T}=-B\Sigma$ which seems to make everything trivial. I will appreciate if someone can help me solve the problem or at least provide some hint.

Comment: It looks like a Lyapunov equation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation maybe vectorization trick can help in your case

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Morad. It sure looks like a Lyapunov equation from the link you've provided. I'll follow the hint.